# What does npm unpublish do?

Tags: npm, verdaccio

I read npm's documentation for [npm unpublish](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/unpublish) but I find it confusing that unpublished versions still show up under a module's `versions` history/tab.

What is the practical impact of unpublishing a version?

- Is it normal that unpublished versions still show up in a module's `versions` tab?
- How do I retrieve the list of active (not unpublished) versions associated with a module?
- What happens if users try to install an unpublished version?
- I assume that users who have cached an unpublished version locally won't be blocked from installing it. Is that correct?